# Ошибка при работе с эксель файлом с использованием библиотеки openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

Я работаю с файлом эксель, в нем несколько листов. Скрипт, написанный на питоне,с применением библиотеки openpyxl вытягивает определенные значения с ячеек листов эксель файла. Проблема моя заключается в следующем: в эксель файле есть три листа, с первых двух данные считываются адекватно и скрипт работает как надо, на третьем листе информация такая же как на первых двух, но почему-то скрипт не хочет с ним работать. Файлы могу предоставить, только вот не знаю как их тут выложить.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
     32         continue
     33 
---> 34     if isPashiyskiy is True and sheet.cell(row=i, column=5).value == ' Нефтенасыщ.' and abs(sheet.cell(row=i, column=4).value) > maxValue:
     35         maxValue = abs(sheet.cell(row=i, column=4).value)
     36

TypeError: bad operand type for abs(): 'NoneType'

Comment: Здесь можно привести ссылку на файлообменник. Кроме этого следует привести ваш код и пример результата, который вы хотите получить

Comment: Прикрепляю ссылку на облако, в папке содержится файл с кодом, также исходный каталог, с которым необходимо работать "ОбосВНК1", и выходной файл, в который записывается результат работы скрипта "Обоснование_ВНК_итог111"
https://cloud.mail.ru/public/4hvF/2dwRLhLJN

Comment: ошибка говорит о том, что вы пытаетесь вызвать функцию `abs(arg)` с None в качестве аргумента. Добавьте в код соответствующую проверку или обработку ошибки (exception)

Comment: Спасибо за комментарий, не подскажете с чем это может быть связано, ведь на других листах идентичная информация, может ли быть дело в типах данных в самих таблицах и как можно привести их к одному типу?